# Hide/show more text button within table cell

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I currently have a html table that is populated using a PHP script. The script loops through a table in my database and outputs the values of 2 fields into two different cells in the table, over and over... The two different values are a review of a university hall, and the name of the person who left the review.

Some reviews can be very long and therefore need to be shortened, using a more/less button. I am unsure how to create this button and get it to appear in every cell of the table (so each review can be expanded).

I'm aware I've not explained this very well, but if anybody knows of a way to achieve this I would be very grateful!

EDIT:

Sorry I should have put my code in here.

Below is the HTML code for the table and the PHP code:

```
<tr>
<td><table class="flat-table flat-table-1" width="100%">
<tr>
</tr>

<tr style="background-color:#FFF;">
<td class="table-head">Name</td>
<td class="table-head">Rating</td>
</tr>

<?php
//run a query to find all the fields in the hall table that belong to the specific     university, using the id in the url ($current_id)
if ($r = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE hall_id = :current_id")) { 
  $r->bindParam(':current_id', $current_id);
  $r->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.

//search table for all fields and save them in $hall
$reviewtemp = $r->fetchAll();
foreach( $reviewtemp as $review) {

//loop and output hall names below
?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $review['name'];?></td>
<td><? echo $review['review']; }}?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The more/less button needs to appear at the bottom of this 'td' -

```
<td><? echo $review['review']; }}?></td>
```

Comment: good questions contain code

Comment: Depends on the more/less button you found on the internet already. Seems like you want to use javascript, though.

Comment: I'm happy to use any method that will work, not only Javascript

Answer (score -1):

why not just output a javascript link that would hide/show additional content?

[show more with javascript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/)

Comment: I have used that link, however it does not work when I use <td class ="more">